# Getting error while running aws cli commands in cygwin

Tags: python, windows, bash, cygwin, aws-cli

I have installed Python in Cygwin as well as in windows. I have installed AWS CLI in windows. it is working fine in command prompt. But in Cygwin it is not working. showing error. Please find the steps which I did to configure.

```
 $ which python
 /usr/bin/python
```

This is Cygwin Python

```
$ aws --version
 C:\Users\Anna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 
'C:\\cygdrive\\c\\Users\\Anna\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Script
s\\aws': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is the error I am facing. Struggling for last 2 days. I reinstalled Cygwin as well.

I tried

```
 hash aws
 hash -t aws
```

Not works for me. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/)?

Comment: No. Not aware of WSL

Comment: In command prompt aws cli works. In cygwin only not working

Comment: I prefer that over Cygwin.

Comment: Any help in cygwin

Comment: Does the documentation say it's supported in Cygwin?

Comment: yes it is mentioned aws cli can be installed in cygwin

Comment: Can you add `aws` to the path?

Comment: like any example. Manually I set in path variable. It didnt worked

Comment: I guess that `aws` is a shell script, so I would debug this one. Somehow it determines the Python path with backslashes, and this ain't good. Perhaps the aws script ignores your PATH when finding Python, but relies on some configuration file? If `aws` is however a compiled executable, your only chance is to search the documentation on how it can be configured.

Comment: Thinking of it: Unless you have an `aws` implementation which is specifically made for Cygwin, it probably won't understand /usr/bin. Instead of this, put the output of `cygpath -m /usr/bin` into your PATH.

Comment: looks like its a mapping issue as its saying its can't find the file, Cygwin uses its own dir structure and needs tweaking to know where things are see -> https://superuser.com/questions/746168/how-to-fix-windows-8-anaconda-cant-open-file-errors-in-cygwin-when-using-abso

Comment: You are mixing cygwin and windows versions of python. the `aws` command is using the windows version of python. You need to install aws under cygwin as well as under windows. My PATH in cygwin is `/home/Doug/bin:/home/Doug/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/lapack:/bin`. Note that there are absolutely no windows folders in my cygwin path. I use `CYGWIN_NOWINPATH=1`. (You will not have lapack unless you installed it.) If you did `pip install -U aws` in the windows shell (cmd or ps), you must do it again in the cygwin shell, i.e. bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to insert following script snippet at the `very top` of C:\Users\Anna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\aws
(After making a backup copy of `aws`, of course)

```
#!/bin/bash
""":"
exec C:/Users/Anna/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe $(cygpath -m $0) ${1+"$@"}
"""
```